# How to optimize rectangle placement in a polygon using python?

Tags: python, optimization, polygon, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem statement where I have to place three rectangles represented by length and breadths in a polygon defined by a list of vertices in a coordinate plane.

##### Conditions:

1. The catch is that I have to maximize the number of rectangles inside the polygon and also the higher the rectangle area the higher its priority of getting placed.
2. The rectangles should not overlap

##### Examples:

Here are some example scenarios to better understand the problem.

1. Given a square -> [(0,0) ,  (0,10)  , (10, 10) , (10, 0)] and three rectanges (L x B) as (2,1) , (5,5) and (2,2), it should give me result as 4 x (5,5) rectangles can be placed.
2. Here's how a octagon shaped polygon and three rectanges of (8,8) (4,2) and (2,1) should look like as a result
   [image]
3. Here's a 10 sided polygon with similar 3 rectangles with different sizes. Note that we can fit comparatively more mid-size and small sized rectangles if we reduce the largest rectangle number but we want to give highest priority to the rectangle that's bigger in size over the smaller one.

edit-1: It was pointed out that some of the rectangles are going outside the polygons in the example below. This was not intended as this example is drawn by hand for this question and the rectangles that are going outside the polygon are just human error.

[image]

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: On the example below some of the rectangles do not fit in the polygon (for example red one on the bottom, blue on the top right). What are rules then?

Comment: It's a hand-drawn example that I created for this question. I'll put this in the main question as well but the rectangles that are going outside the polygon are just human error and this is not intended.